# Creating a Discord-Bot command with "multiple" parameters

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to design a command that will allow a user to call the bot using a specific command, and have the bot read in the entire string that the user passes in.

The problem here, is that the discord bot only takes in the first word following the command, and ignores all the rest.

```
commands.CreateCommand("sarcastify").Parameter("input", ParameterType.Multiple).Do(async (e) =>
        {

            String userInput = e.GetArg("input");
            String output = sarcastify(userInput);

            await e.Channel.SendMessage(output);               

        });
```

If you couldn't tell I'm making a command that allows the user to request a "Sarcastic" version of the input text, AKA that one spongebob meme.

Anyways, when the command is called, only the first word is taken in

```
//In discord chat window
$sarcastify This program works


//Response
tHiS
```

Is there any way for the Discord bot to take in the entire string for parsing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly sure how the Discord.NET API handles the parameter name (beyond single parameters), but I do know that when discord reads in command parameters, it stores them in an array called 'Args' which can be accessed and used like a normal array of strings.

so if you ran

```
$sarcastify this program works
```

then within the command function: e.Args[0] = "this", e.Args[1] = "program", e.Args[2] = "works" e.t.c

So if you want the input as one string, we can just use the string.Join() method on the array, so your code would look like this:

```
commands.CreateCommand("sarcastify")
    .Parameter("input",ParameterType.Multiple)
    .Do(async (e) =>
    {
        String userInput = string.Join(" ", e.Args);
        String output = sarcastify(userInput);
        await e.Channel.SendMessage(output);               
    });
```

With this code the input:

```
$sarcastify this program works
```

would produce the desired output : tHiS pRoGrAm WoRkS

:)